# How to delete n characters from m position from a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

For some reason most Ruby string functions work with predetermined substrings and patterns. I don't have any assumptions about the string's contents, but I need to just delete n chars from m-th position. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
str = "abcdefghij"
m = 4
n = 3
str.slice!(m,n) # => "efg"
p str # => "abcdhij"
```

Comment: In this example exclamation mark acts unexpectedly to me. Why would it return and save to the variable different things?

Comment: `slice` would return "efg" and leave `str` unchanged. `slice!` does change `str`. It is not "saving to a variable", it is mutating a string.

Comment: Yes, incorect terms. I mean, why it returns and mutates in different ways. I thought that mutating and not mutating equivalents should behave the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[slice!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-slice)**

```
str='Apple'

str.slice![1..3] #=> ppl

puts str

#=> Ae
```